# How to examine the JSON response from a REST endpoint from Chrome's dev console?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, rest, google-chrome

I have a REST endpoint as follows:

```
http://localhost:4212/api/MyRestEndpoint/?arg1=val1
```

When you hit this endpoint it returns some JSON data.

I want to hit this endpoint from Chrome's developer console. This is what I'm typing in there:

```
$http = angular.element(document.body).injector().get('$http');
$http.get("http://localhost:4212/api/MyRestEndpoint/?arg1=val1")
```

When, I do this, I can see from the endpoint's perspective that it was called. That's great. However, the response I see in the console is the image below. It's just a promise. How can I see the actual JSON structure that is returned??

[image]

Comment: change your last line to : $http.get("http://localhost:4212/api/MyRestEndpoint/?arg1=val1").then(function(response) { console.log(response.data) });

Comment: Why don't you look in the network tab instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to actually see the data, look at the network tab. But it will be more useful for you to set up a callback so you can correctly use the data that is returned.

```
    $http.get("http://localhost:4212/api/MyRestEndpoint/?arg1=val1").then(function(data){
console.log(data);
}
```

Possibly console.log(JSON.stringify(data)) will make it more readable.

Answer (score 1):

Sine $http returns Promise object, you need the then...catch statement:

```
$http.get("http://localhost:4212/api/MyRestEndpoint/?arg1=val1").then(function(response) { console.log(response.data) }).catch(function (error) { console.log(error.data) });
```

At that point you are logging your $http, result are not received yet.